# How to produce a compilation error on implicit long to double conversion?

Tags: java, double, long-integer

Is there a way to get the Java compiler to produce an *error* when a "long" is *implicitly* converted to a "double", as this can cause data loss?

EDIT: The reason I cannot accept the answer from Alex, is that it defeats my purpose. What I want to do is create a *minimal* "functor" API, that *does not cause garbage* by directly supporting primitive types too, instead of only supporting object types using generics. But to keep the number of interfaces small, I want to use as few types as possible. With just double and Object, for parameters and return value, I support (almost) all types without causing garbage, nor loosing any data (boolean does not convert to double, but does not cause garbage by autoboxing either, AFAIK, so it's OK not to support it explicitly). Since all primitive types, except boolean and long, can safely, and implicitly be converted to double, I have almost all my needs covered.

That is where the question comes from: if I don't add explicit support for long in that API, how to prevent long being used at all, as it would leading to bugs? And of course, using java.lang.Double instead of double would cause garbage, and therefore make the API pointless.

Before anyone asks, I'll say that I want to use the API in real-time Android games where "garbage" is a real issue, unlike the JVM.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I think [this modification to that](http://ideone.com/7CSoR8) captures the issue. Note that `(double)Long.MAX_VALUE` is `9.223372036854776E18` (`9223372036854776000`), whereas `Long.MAX_VALUE` is `9223372036854775807`. Data has been lost, thanks to the imperfect nature of IEEE-754 double-precision numbers. (That's not a dig at them, they're *very useful*, but there *is* data loss here.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are correct, there is data loss there. However, JLS specifically acknowledges the possibility of "silent" loss of precision.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Yeah, your answer to the question below is correct (of course). I just thought that initial link/comment gave the impression there was no data loss, so I thought I'd flag up the loss that occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. According to Java Language Specification, `long` to `double` is considered a *widening conversion*. It never triggers a compile or a run-time error.

> [(JLS, section 5.1.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) Despite the fact that loss of precision may occur, a widening primitive conversion
>   never results in a run-time exception (§11.1.1).

Comment: I'll wait a day or two, before I accept your answer, in case there is some compiler/Maven/Ant -plugin that already checks for that. Basically, *any* error would solve the problem, even if it does not come from the compiler itself.

Comment: @SebastienDiot If any tool has it, it would probably be IntelliJ. They have an impressive collection of code analysis settings, see if spotting precision loss like that is one of the checks that they provide.

Comment: In the absence of any "known existing solution", while it might be possible for me to check it with my own compiler plugin, I'll choose your answer as the most "correct".

Answer (score 1):

Difficult and requiring some research.

**The first idea - Byte Code**

You could use byte code manipulation. There are some [instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings) like `l2d` (long-to-double) that might be found.

Maybe combined with annotations.

Make your own annotation to suppress processing for this check.
Do annotation processing.

**The second idea - JavaME**

Java ME which might forbid the use of doubles altogether.

**The third idea - Java parsing and data analysis**

Java compiler toolkit.

Comment: I think only the last idea helps. I assume, although I do not know for sure, that "double d = 1L" compiles to the same code as "double d = (double) 1L". That is, I suspect that once you have bytecode, you cannot differentiate between implicit and explicit conversion. The second idea is totally the opposite of what I want; I want to use double, but not long.

Comment: To be more specific, I want to allow *explicit* cast from long to double, assuming the programmer knows what they are doing, but only flag implicit conversions, which were probably not intended.

Comment: @SebastienDiot But a programmer who knows what he's doing won't write an explicit cast (either) - he *knows* its implicitly casted, so why would he write an explicit cast?

Comment: @Durandal What I mean is, *if I would get errors on implicit cast*, and *I know my long "fits in a double" (does not use more then 52 bits)*, and I wanted to pass the long as a double, rather then a java.lang.Long object, to prevent garbage production, THEN I would use and *explicit* cast to double, to tell the compiler that this is not an error, and should not be flagged as an error. Of course, casting a long to a double explicitly only makes sense if I got an error on implicit casting, which is until now not the case.

Comment: Would it not be even more qualitative if `double` were alltogether replaced by `BigDecimal`? No more `10 * 0.2 != 2.0`. (Depends on the usage of double and yes, BigDecimal is a PITA.)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to produce an error on implicit conversion, as stated in the other answer. If the overhead is acceptable, you can force an explicit check using autoboxing conversions by declaring a variable or method parameter as `java.lang.Double`; the compiler will silently box primitive `double` values but will throw a compile exception for `long` expressions.

```
public class Doubles {

  static double asDouble(Double d) {
    return d.doubleValue();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long l = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    double d = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    System.out.println(d + " " + asDouble(d));
    System.out.println(l + " " + asDouble(l)); // Compile error.
  }
}
```

Of course, there are limitations to this approach - it won't uncover problems in existing code. But strategic use of it could provide some safety from loss of precision in important areas of your code.

Comment: Interesting idea. It solves my question "literally", but not my "purpose". I'll edit my question to clarify.